# How can I force the device user to use a specific version of HMS core that inline with some HMS services?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

some of my App features need a specific version of HMS core to be work with so the feature can run with no issues, I tried to find a way to force device user to update the HMS Core to the latest version, to make sure the app will not crash, but I can't find any way so please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

No such interface is provided. If the current HMS Core does not meet the requirements, the HMS automatically guides the subscriber to upgrade the HMS Core.

I have tried to code for this senarior before, you could also give below code a try：

```
public void checkUpdate(Context context) {     
           int requiredVersion = 50005300;     
    Log.d("mymsg", "" + 
          HMSPackageManager.getInstance(context).getHmsVersionCode());     
    Log.d("mymsg", "" + 
       HMSPackageManager.getInstance(context).hmsVerHigherThan(requiredVersion));    
    
    if (HMSPackageManager.getInstance(context).hmsVerHigherThan(requiredVersion))
     {         initDialog(MainActivity.this);     } } 
    
    
private void initDialog(Activity activity) {     
     new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)             
          .setMessage("Please update HMS Core")             
          .setCancelable(false)             
          .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> {
              intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);    
              intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);       
              intent.setData(Uri.parse("appmarket://details?
              id="+HMSPackageManager.getInstance(activity).getHMSPackageName()));  
              activity.startActivity(intent);             
             })  
            .create()            
            .show(); 
    }
```

This code checks whether the current HMS Core version is earlier than the required version. If it is earlier than the required version, the AppGallery Hms Core download page is displayed.